# Monitoring Cpu, iops and memory on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, monitor, cost-management, cost-based-optimizer

I want to monitor the cpu/iops/memory usage for my appliation in an azure vm. I need to run it different times for different families to chose the best fit for my app. Should I use Azure monitor or a cli app inside my VM? Which are the best tools to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone with [Azure Monitor Log Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/) as it has rich metrics to monitor VM; [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftcomputevirtualmachines) are the list of supported metrics. To monitor the granular level of logs that might not be monitored by default by Log Analytics, I would leverage [custom logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-custom-logs), [performance counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-performance-counters), [data collector API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api), etc.